# How to find document matching the value in array type field in Mongodb

Tags: json, mongodb

```
{      
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b98e5d17d542a2560ec026d"), 
    "RequestID" : "1536746958",     
    "JSON_Request" : [2,"1536746958","Heartbeat",{}],    
    "JSON_Response" : [3,"1536746958",{"currentTime":"2018-09-12T10:09:21.435Z"}] 
}
```

Want to fetch the documents which contains "Heartbeat" in Field "JSON_Request"

Answer (score 0):

Please try this `db.getCollection('request').find({JSON_Request: 'Heartbeat'})` MongoDb 4.x

Or MongoDb 3.6 `db.getCollection('request').find({ JSON_Request: { $elemMatch: {$eq: 'Heartbeat'} }})` Check [elemMatch MongoDb 3.6](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch) too

Comment: already tried, not getting anything

Comment: Have you used correct collection name?
I already tried it locally, and above command works well

Comment: yes, I am using the correct collection name. Thank you though.

Comment: What is your MongoDB version?

Comment: Mongodb version 3.6.0

Comment: Updated answer, I think last answer is the correct query too

Answer (score 0):

Try [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) like so:

```
collection.find({ JSON_Request: { $elemMatch: { $eq: "Heartbeat" } } })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$in` operator of MongoDB. The link to the official doc: [Click](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)

Example:
I have two documents in the queryAns collection as

> ```
> db.queryAns.find({}).pretty()
> ```

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b98e5d17d542a2560ec026d"),
    "RequestID" : "1536746958",
    "JSON_Request" : [
        2,
        "1536746958",
        "Heartbeat1",
        {

        }
    ],
    "JSON_Response" : [
        3,
        "1536746958",
        {
            "currentTime" : "2018-09-12T10:09:21.435Z"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b98e5d17d542a2560ec024d"),
    "RequestID" : "1536746958",
    "JSON_Request" : [
        2,
        "1536746958",
        "Heartbeat",
        {

        }
    ],
    "JSON_Response" : [
        3,
        "1536746958",
        {
            "currentTime" : "2018-09-12T10:09:21.435Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

and to filter out only results which contains "Heartbeat" in the "JSON_Request",

> db.queryAns.find({"JSON_Request": {$in: ["Heartbeat"]}}).pretty()

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b98e5d17d542a2560ec024d"),
    "RequestID" : "1536746958",
    "JSON_Request" : [
        2,
        "1536746958",
        "Heartbeat",
        {

        }
    ],
    "JSON_Response" : [
        3,
        "1536746958",
        {
            "currentTime" : "2018-09-12T10:09:21.435Z"
        }
    ]
}
```